# Format date column in datatables

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, datatables, laravel-datatables

i need format date in my datatable column, i´m reading documentation, but i don´t know how i can to do it.

i have this code for create my datatable:

```
var callTable = $('#calls').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        language: {
            url: "{{ asset('js/plugins/datatables/spanish.json') }}",
        },
        buttons: [
            'pdf'
        ],
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: "{{ route('jefasala.listado.getCall') }}",
        columnDefs: [{
            'targets': 0,
            'searchable': false,
            'orderable': false,
            'className': 'dt-body-center',
            'render': function (data, type, full, meta){
                return '<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" name="id[]" value="' + $('<div/>').text(data).html() + '">';
            },
        }],
        select: {
            style:    'os',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        },
        // if datatable it´s correct created
        "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
            fillSelectOperator();

            // this change operator for call
            $(".select_operator").on("change", function(e){
                let callId = $(e.target).closest('tr').find("td:eq(1)").html();
                let operatorId = $(this).val();
                let token = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'); 

                var modalConfirm = function(callback){
  
                    $("#modalConfirm").modal('show');

                    $("#confirmOperator").on("click", function(){
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "{{ route('jefasala.listado.llamadas.asignar') }}",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: { "callId": callId, "operatorId": operatorId, "_token":token },
                            success: function(response){
                                $("#assignOk").show();
                                $("#assignOk").append(response);
                                location.reload();
                            },
                            error: function(xhr){
                                $("#errorAssign").show();
                                $("#errorAssign").append(xhr.responseText);
                            }
                        });
                        $("#modalConfirm").modal('hide');
                    });
                    
                    $("#cancelOperator").on("click", function(){
                        callback(false);
                        $("#modalConfirm").modal('hide');
                    });
                };

                modalConfirm(function(confirm){
                    if(confirm){
                       console.log("eee");
                    }else{
                        //Acciones si el usuario no confirma
                        $("#result").html("NO CONFIRMADO");
                    }
                });
            });
```

all data for fill it, it´s in db, i´m working with backend `laravel 5.6` and datatables `yajra`.

My table it´s:

```
<table id="calls" class="table table-hover table-condensed display mb-5" style="width:100%">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <input style="style=border: none; background: transparent; font-size: 14px;" type='checkbox' id='checkall' class="checkall">
            </th>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Direccion</th>
            <th>Provincia</th>
            <th>Ciudad</th>
            <th>Teleoperador/a</th>
            <th>Reasignar</th>
            <th>Est.Llamada</th>
            <th>Est.Cita</th>
            <th>F.Asignacion</th>
            <th>Acciones</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Direccion</th>
            <th>Direccion</th>
            <th>Provincia</th>
            <th>Ciudad</th>
            <th>Teleoperador/a</th>
            <th>Reasignar</th>
            <th>Estado Llamada</th>
            <th>Estado Cita</th>
            <th>Fecha Asignacion</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>{{-- TABLE CALL --}}
```

and in my controller return instance of Datatable:

```
$llamadas = DB::table('users')->join('llamada', 'users.id', '=', 'llamada.id_teleoperadora')
                                      ->join('llamada_estado', 'llamada_estado.id', '=', 'llamada.id_estado')
                                      ->join('cita', 'llamada.id', '=', 'cita.id_llamada')
                                      ->join('cita_estado', 'cita.id_estado', '=', 'cita_estado.id')
                                      ->select(
                                                'llamada.id AS identi','llamada.nomape as nombre',
                                                'llamada.ciudad as ciudad', 'llamada.provincia as provincia',
                                                'llamada.direccion as direccion','llamada.cp as cp', 
                                                'llamada.telefono as telefono','users.nombre AS teleoperadora',
                                                'llamada_estado.nombre AS estado', 'cita_estado.nombre as estadoCita',
                                                'llamada.fecha_asignacion as fechaAsignacion', 'llamada.updated_at as updated'
                                            )
                                      ->get();

        
                                    
        return Datatables::of($llamadas)
            ->addColumn('action', function(){
                $btn = '<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalCall" class="editCall btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                            <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
                        </a>';
                return $btn;
            })
            ->rawColumns(['action'])
            ->make(true);
```

But i don´t know how i can to format this date.

Thanks for help.

Comment: How do you want it formatted?

Comment: @BeerusDev i want to formated in DD-MM-YYYY HH::mm:ss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve my question with:

```
{ data: 'fechaAsignacion', render: function (data, type, row) {
                return moment(new Date(data).toString()).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
                } 
            },
```

In my column with `date` use moment to create format with my format i have to include moment library jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can use the createRow callback from datatable

```
fnCreatedRow : function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex)
            {
                  let date = (aData[1]); // assume date is in column 1
                  // format date here
                  $('td:eq(1)', nRow).html(date);
            },
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, but i don´t understand very well how i can to do this

Comment: Sorry but so you need to learn more basics instead of doing such complex things. You only have to put my code in the creation of the datable. That is super easy